# how to put "uk-toggle" in rails link_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, uikit

I have a link "Signin"

this is my code

```
<a href="#modal-example" class="uk-float-right" uk-toggle>
 <span uk-icon='icon: user'></span>
 <span>Sign in</span>
 <span uk-icon='icon: chevron-down'></span>
</a>
```

When I click Signin the modal will show.

Now, I want to change it to rails link_to tag.

```
<%= link_to "#modal-example", class:"uk-float-right", uk-toggle do %>
 <span uk-icon='icon: user'></span>
 <span>Sign in</span>
 <span uk-icon='icon: chevron-down'></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

```
<%= link_to "#modal-example", class:"uk-float-right", "uk-toggle": "" do %>
    <span uk-icon='icon: user'></span>
    <span>Sign in</span>
    <span uk-icon='icon: chevron-down'></span>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to class:"uk-float-right", "id": "#modal-example", "data": {"uk-toggle": ""} do %>

#rest of your code
```

## Updated:

```
<%= link_to class:"uk-float-right", "id": "#modal-example", "data": {"uk-toggle": ""}, "uk-toggle": "" do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally for boolean attributes, you can pass the value `true`.

The commonly used attribute is `disabled`

In your case that would be

```
<%= link_to "#modal-example", class:"uk-float-right", "uk-toggle" => true do %>
 <span uk-icon='icon: user'></span>
 <span>Sign in</span>
 <span uk-icon='icon: chevron-down'></span>
<% end %>
```